# webpack: syntax error with babel-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm starting to learn react with a tutorial. But `webpack` is not working as expected.

So here is my simple `webpack.conf.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app-client.js",
    output: {
        filename: "public/bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules|app-server.js)/,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Also I installed all the modules:

```
npm install -g webpack
npm install webpack react babel-loader babel-core
```

But when running `webpack`, I got the following error message:

```
ERROR in ./app-client.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: app-client.js: Unexpected token (4:13)
  2 | var APP = require('./components/APP');
  3 | 
> 4 | React.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
    |              ^
```

In my understanding, `babel-loader` is supposed to take care of that. But it looks like it's not making the effort.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you configuring babel with the [react preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/)?

Comment: No. The tutorial didn't mention that.

Comment: I'd try another tutorial, perhaps this one https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html

Comment: I recommend to have a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel 6 doesn't do anything by itself. In order to properly process JSX, you need to have the following in your `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": ["react"]
}
```

Also, you need to make sure you install that preset using NPM:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-core react react-dom babel-preset-react
```

A good place to start is the official React [getting started page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: Also you can add preset parameter right in `webpack.conf.js` without `.babelrc` file using `loader: 'babel?presets[]=react` or [query parameter option](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options) for loader.